# Jquery onchange issue in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

Actually, onchange of tag need to change and display actual record for example (if change Men means mens record will open(display)) i need to pass variable inside option value how will pass.

Here my Html code:

```
<select name="category" id ='category' onchange='gender(this)' style="background:transparent">
                  <option id ='gender' hidden="hidden">Gender</option>
                <?php foreach($mens as $row){?>
                  <option value="men">Boy's</option>
                  <option value="girl">Girl's</option>
                <?php }?>
              </select>
```

Here my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#category").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
              $( "#list" ).submit();
            alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText + " Value: " + selectedValue);
        });
    });
</script>
```

here with my Php code:

```
$men ="SELECT * FROM `tbl_master_property` where status=0";
    $men_result=$conn->query($men);
     $men_projects = array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($men_result)){ 
        $men_projects[] = $row;
        }
         $mens = $men_projects; 
         echo '<pre>'; print_r($mens);die;
```

I print my $mens it is display :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pg_id] => 1
            [name] => Sri Manikanta New Luxury Paying Guest For Men
            [gender] => 0
            [location_id] => 0

        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [pg_id] => 2
            [name] => Srivari New Executive Paying Guest For Men
            [gender] => 0
            [location_id] => 0

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [pg_id] => 3
            [name] => Temple View New Executive Pg For Ladies
            [gender] => 1
            [location_id] => 0

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [pg_id] => 4
            [name] => Srinivasa Luxury Guest For Men
            [gender] => 1
            [location_id] => 0   
        )
```

Comment: What part is not working?

Comment: html part is not working sir, how to pass value to option value

Comment: Are you talking about getting the `$mens` array to populate the `<option>`? So it would be `<option name="0">Sri Manikanta New Luxury Paying Guest For Men</option>` etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the options to populate from the `$mens` array:

```
<?php foreach($mens as $row){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['gender'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
<?php }?>
```

If this is not what you mean, you may have to clarify more.

---

**EDIT 1:**

If you have a large list of items to draw from, you will want to use ajax, but if your sample is relatively small, you can conceivably just use an array to draw from.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/z50m5hnz/:

```
<select name="category" id ='category' style="background:transparent">
    <option id ='gender' hidden="hidden">Gender</option>
    <option value="men">Men's</option>
    <option value="girl">Ladies</option>
</select>

<select name="items" id="items">
<select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dropdown_items = <?php echo json_encode($mens) ?>;
    $(function () {
        $("#category").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            var opts = [];
            $.each(dropdown_items,function(k,v){
                if(selectedValue == 'men' && v.gender == 0) {
                    opts.push('<option name="'+v.gender+'">'+v.name+'</option>');
                }
                else if(selectedValue == 'girl' && v.gender == 1) {
                    opts.push('<option name="'+v.gender+'">'+v.name+'</option>');
                }
            });

            $('#items').html(opts.join(''));
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

This is my last guess on what you want, from comments I think maybe you want to reload the page but send the the value selection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#category").change(function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            window.location =   '?select='+selectedValue;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry sir, if dropdown menu is there it have two value (Men & ladies) if i click Men means men records will display page

Comment: Oh you mean you want to choose `<option value="men">Men's</options>` it will fetch the array for mens and populate another dropdown to select from? So the two mens arrays from the `$mens` array?

Comment: Ok now I don't know what you mean anymore...you want to select `men` or `girl` from the dropdown which then automatically takes you to a new page that will then pull the data for the men or ladies? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: So on change, submit the form or just send the selected value? Which one?

Comment: just submit the form

Comment: So `onchange` you want it to submit `?gender=men` or `?gender=girl` depending on what the selection is?

Comment: Ok, I edited with my last guess on what you are looking for...see if that is what you are meaning.