# how to get form POST value in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need how to get form POST value on the same page. Below is my script to try and extract the value as well as the form html:

```
<form action="" id ='list' name= "list" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="select">
        <select name="lamp" id ="lamp" onchange="gender(this)" style="background:transparent">
            <option id ='gender' hidden="hidden">Gender</option>
            <option value="0">Boy's</option>
            <option value="1">Girl's</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Php code:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {  
    $pg_type =$_POST['lamp'];
    echo $pg_type;die;
}
```

I have echo the my variabe it is showing like:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: lamp in C:\xampp\www\htdocs\rentozy\assets\includes\list-header.php on line 20

Comment: how does form will send request to your php file until you haven't define `action=""` ?

Comment: replace `isset($_POST)` with `isset($_POST['lamp'])`

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with your inline javascript `gender(this)` sending the wrong value since there is no submit on this form. Probably related to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219386/jquery-onchange-issue-in-php

Comment: action is same page only

Comment: As `$_POST` is a superglobal, I would believe `isset($_POST)` will always return true, even if it is empty (ie on initial page load). So you may want to check the for the actual field `isset($_POST['lamp'])`

Comment: i checked actual field like this code but not getting POST value sir isset($_POST['lamp']) .showing issue for :Notice: Undefined index: lamp in C:\xampp\w

Comment: What does the javascript function `gender(this)`?

Answer (score 1):

The form:
1.  be consistent - use `"` or `'` but not both for the HTML attributes;
2.  set the name of `select` to *gender* and remove the first `option` since it is nonsense in this example;

```
<form action="" id="list" name="list" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="select">
        <select name="gender" id="gender" style="background:transparent">
            <option value="0">Boy's</option>
            <option value="1">Girl's</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:
1. change the if check to the exact key such as `gender` not to the whole `POST` array
2. To check what was actually send via POST you can print the whole array:

```
if (isset($_POST['gender'])) {  
    $pg_type=$_POST['gender'];
    die('Gender value in $pg_type is: ' . $pg_type); // for debugging
}
else {
     // for debugging
     print_r($_POST);
}
```